# How I access to the VSCode parser?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm making an extension that builds an UML from the code.
I need to access to the vscode java parser in order to naviguate in my code from my extension.

But I don't find anything, can you help me ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I specify a bit,

I'm making a vscode extension and I need to explore your code when you use my extension,

I need to have the class, package ... and their attribute. I need to have the AST.

Comment: Have you referred to the API page of the VSCode? such as [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features)